# C#, Json deserialization: avoid empty string array elements

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

My json array, which comes to me from the server, can contain empty string elements. I want to remove them at the level of deserialization.

```
{
   "Highlights":[
         "Þingvellir National Park",
         "Gullfoss Waterfall",
         "Geysir Geothermal Area",
         "Laugarvatn","Kerið Crater",
         "Hveragerði Hot Spring Area",
         "",
         ""
   ]
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<string> Highlights { get; set; }
}
```

I want that if the element is `string.IsNullOrEmpty (element) == true`, then it is not added to the array.

In this case, the number of elements after deserialization in the `TestModel.Highlights` array should be 6, not 8, because 2 of them are empty.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any reason you can't just run through the list afterwards and remove null or empty elements? That's likely to be simpler than persuading whatever JSON parser you're using to do it on the fly.

Comment: There is no reason or benefit to doing this, just do a simple Linq `Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))` on `Highlights`

Comment: implementing your own `JsonConverter` would be probably very YAGNI :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to iterate trough the collection and check for null or empty strings as suggested in comments.
The harder and ugly(for this situation) way would be to create a custom `JsonConverter` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574144/4975079) answer like:

```
class IgnoreEmptyItemsConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        foreach (var obj in array)
        {
            // really custom way (not really generic)
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()))
            {
                list.Add(obj.ToObject<T>(serializer));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and this can be used in your model like:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IgnoreEmptyItemsConverter<string>))]
    public List<string> Highlights { get; set; }
}
```