# Handling Empty dictionary when deserializing JSON response in .NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The structure of the JSON response is in the format

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>>
```

which is to be deserialized.

Sometimes the inner dictionary is received as empty , {} which throws an error

```
Error converting value \"{}\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Double]'. Path '513215', line 1, position 14.
```

Even on trying below piece of code : it gives the same error

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                };

var json_response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>>(response, settings);
```

How to handle this error and what are the best practices to handle it?

Example JSON which causes error

[image]

Comment: I don't see the JSON response your deserializing? `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>>` is just the type you want to deserialize to.

Comment: @RoadRunner Do you want example response or ? The last line of code is being used for deserialization

Comment: @Kitwradr Why do you have `{}` in the first place? That is an empty object. And `{}` is not null hence your settings will not work. Also, `Json.NET` expects a dictionary to be an `object` or `null`. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572652/newtonsoft-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-how-to-ignore-empty-objects

Comment: Please, share the example json, which causes an error

Comment: Added the screenshot in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be to not send empty dictionaries and should always send `null` instead of `{}`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from checking the response for empty set or bad value before you go thru this deserialization. I do it all the time. :)

Comment: How do we check whether an inner dictionary is empty? @Rich K.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your JSON, I think the problem lies within you JSON itself. Not sure because you are using a visualizer. That "{...lots of stuff...}" is not going to be parsed correctly because you have quotes inside.

I would take your raw JSON over to https://jsonlint.com/ and see what it has to say. Once you get that worked out you probably will stop throwing errors. BTW your first "string" 513215 ... is not a string in the world of JSON, it's a number. It needs to be surrounded by quotes. Once again this could be the visualizer.

Don't forget about https://www.json.org/ to see all those JSON rules.